# Changing at runtime the consumer-max-rate of a hornetQ Queue

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

I have set a hornetQ in the standalone.xml of JBoss 7.

I also create a connection factory like that:

```
<connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
   <connectors>
       <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
   </connectors>
   <entries>
       <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
   </entries>
   <consumer-max-rate>10</consumer-max-rate>
</connection-factory>
```

Everything runs as expected but let's say I want to change the consumer-max-rate live when everything is running. How would I achieve that?

I understand I have to use this method

```
HornetQConnectionFactory.setConsumerMaxRate(int consumerMaxRate)
```

but how do I get the HornetQConnectionFactory?

edit: I managed to get the HornetQConnectionFactory and set the max rate but this is not reloading at runtime. I have to stop and start again the ConnectionFactory. Is it possible to do it at runtime?

Comment: This seems somehow related, it is a similar problem. http://hwellmann.blogspot.gr/2011/10/jboss-as-7-catching-up-with-java-ee-6.html

Comment: The problem is that not all the modules of JBoss 7 are exposed. So as described in the article http://hwellmann.blogspot.gr/2011/10/jboss-as-7-catching-up-with-java-ee-6.html one solution is to define HornetQ as a global module. That way you can access it and set the consumer rate.

The problem that still stands however is that it doesn't change on runtime.